# Can linux-x64 and similar dot net publish tags be used for conditional compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-compilation

I am trying to compile code conditionally (and DLL imports, most importantly) based on the targeted OS. I find no shortage of articles explaining how to compile conditionally based on the OS the project is *built from*, or how to execute code conditionally based on the OS the project *runs on*. But not how how to compile conditionally based on the OS the project *will run on*.

I could go the `p:DefineConstants` way, but I feel I shouldn't need to as I already specify `win-x64` / `linux-x64` in the `dotnet publish` command.

Is there a way to avoid repeating myself and use that information directly ? I was under the impression according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives that `WINDOWS` would be defined for `win-x64` compilations, but it's not.

Comment: You can with Core 7, but not with Net.  The purpose of Core was to allow the same executable to run on Windows, Linux, and MAC.  So there is a different Run Time library for each OS so the same exe will be able to run on all three OS.

Comment: While it's not an answer to your question, do note that P/Invoke is not like imports in native code, in that nothing will break or fail if you have references to libraries and functions in them that don't exist -- such things won't fail until the first time the method is actually called. Given this it's perfectly possible to declare all the imports you want/need unconditionally, and switch the actual implementations used only at runtime (leaving it up to the JIT to eliminate dead code, through judicious use of `static readonly` fields), and such a code base is (IMO) much easier to manage.

Comment: You can detect the current OS type by calling `Environment.OsType.Platform`. That will lead to a run-time condition, not a compile-time one though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, that would solve part of the issue, but I also - only for the Windows version - use a package that uses DllImports =/